Karate 1.5.0 - Surefire/Cucumber reporting setup
Using Karate 1.5.0 (java 22), I am not able to modify the code to be working. Previously I used version 1.2.0 (java 11) and now I experiment with 1.5.0 but I am not successful with modifying the code.
Any suggestions to improve the code to make it working?:
POM:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssp-uc-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>1.5.0</karate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.7.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumberReporting</projectName>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

PortalTestRunner.java
package ui;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class PortalTestRunner {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {

        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");

        String outputPath = "target/surefire-reports";

        String tag;
        tag = (System.getProperty("karate.tag")).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(tag);

        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:api", "classpath:ui").tags("@"+tag+",~@COMPONENT").parallel(1);

        generateReport(outputPath);
        assertTrue(results.getFailCount() == 0, results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    public static void generateReport (String outputPath){
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(outputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);

        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"),"ProjectXXX");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}

With the files mentioned above, I get an error associated with reporting:
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:628)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:250)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1256)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:939)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:903)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:280)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:203)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:255)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:201)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:361)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:314)


PortalTestRunner.java is in the setup mentioned above worked fine with Karate 1.2.0. "Karate reports" are saved successfully.
Probably I am facing some incompatibility. Any idea? Many thanks!

Karate is not compatible with cucumber, and that can be the reason. since you are on such an old version I can only suggest you go through all the release notes. or maybe starting with a fresh project and copying over your existing project piece by piece may be the way to go
